# Excel Power query: search one folder deep

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am doing a power query in excel and im just using it to list all files in a specific directory.

I have two problems:

1. I cannot choose a sharepoint for the query. I may only choose folders on my hard drive. Is it possible to use a network sharepoint?
2. When I choose the folder i want, the query digs deep in all subfolders and list all files. However, i want it to search max 1 subfolder deep. and not 300. Is it possible?

Thanks for anyone who can help me! much appreciated

PS: If there is a vba code which lists all files one subfolder deep, this would also be a great solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can choose a network SharePoint folder by using the SharePoint Folder connector under Get Data. But you have to *only use the root folder as your target* for the URL. That will bring up a list of all files that exist within the hierarchy under that root folder. From there, use the Transform Data button (not the Combine & Transform Data button). Then you can rely upon the Folder Path column to filter for your desired actual folder.

   [The Folder connector works similarly to the SharePoint Folder connector, in that it will bring up a list of all files that exist within the hierarchy under the targeted folder.]
2. I am not aware of it being possible to go straight to your desired folder using either the SharePoint Folders connector or the Folders connector.

Answer (score 0):

filter the results of your list of there is a PATH column

Comment: Since your answer is extremely short and doesn't use ant code, you should maybe put it as a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 0):

For question 2.

Connect to SharePoint as usual, then in the formula bar change SharePoint.Files to SharePoint.Contents

This will change the pulled data view to a table allowing you to click into the word "table" on the left of the rows of data so you can navigate to the relevant directory.